# ISO8583 encoding data fields

Tags: c#, socket, stream, tcp, e-commerce

I just want to confirm that my [ISO8583](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8583) format is correct.

Example:

For the data field 35, the length of the data is 36, so I put 36 before the 4842. Then all the data is inserted in a string (`dataISO`). This `dataISO` variable is then sent to another function `SendISO()`.

```
private void btnSend_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string command = cboISOCommand.SelectionBoxItem.ToString();
    string dataISO = "";

    if (command == "Pre-Auth")
    {
        string dataLength = "019A";
        string TPDU = "6001010000";
        string MTI = "0100";
        string BITMAP = "3020078020C00204";
        string ProCode = "380000"; // 3
        string Amount = "000000010000"; // 4
        string STAN = "000031"; // 11
        string POSEM = "051"; // 22
        string PANSequence = "001"; // 23
        string FunctionCode = "101"; // 24
        string ConditionCode = "00"; // 25
        string Track2 = "36484200000000009=15000000000000000000"; //35
        string TerminalID = "00000000"; //41
        string IdentificationCode = "000000000000000"; //42
        string ReservedISO = "2725F2A02045882023C008407A0000000031010950500000080009A031407229C01009F0206000000000010";
        ReservedISO +="9F03060000000000009F0902008C9F100706010A03A0A0029F1A0204589F1E0831313731313534399F26";
        ReservedISO +="081344604C7E2C7B589F2701809F3303E0B0C89F34031E03009F3501229F360204379F3704746733F19F4";
        ReservedISO +="104000000079F530152"; //55
        string ReservedPrivate = "006000019"; //62

        string total = dataLength + TPDU + MTI + BITMAP + ProCode + Amount + STAN + POSEM + PANSequence + FunctionCode + ConditionCode + Track2 + TerminalID + IdentificationCode + ReservedISO + ReservedPrivate;
        dataISO = total;
    }


    _controller.SendISO(client2, dataISO);
}

//To Send ISO Data Over TCP Socket
public void SendISO(TcpClient client, string isoData)
{
    string ip =     ((IPEndPoint)client.Client.RemoteEndPoint).Address.ToString();
    int port = ((IPEndPoint)client.Client.RemoteEndPoint).Port;

    if (!client.Connected)
    {
        OnControllerErrorFunction(
            new ControllerErrorArguments(String.Format("02<> IP {0} Port {1} not Connected", ip, Convert.ToString(port)), "DISCONNECTED"));
        return;
    }
    try
    {
        NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(isoData);

        if (stream.CanWrite)
        {
            stream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
            stream.Flush();

            onControllerRawDataFunction(
                    new ControllerRawArguments(
                        string.Format("Send Controller {0} : {1}", ip, isoData)));
        }
    }
    catch (Exception err)
    {
        OnControllerErrorFunction(
            new ControllerErrorArguments(string.Format("02<>Controller {0} Error on sending data : {1} ", ip, isoData), err.Message));
        WriteSystemLog(err.Message, "Send Data To Controller");
        return;
    }
}
```

And for the function to send ISO Data over a TCP socket, is it correct in terms of the encoding before sending it using `stream.Write`?

Comment: [Cross-posted from Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33870873/c-sharp-iso8583-encoding-data-fields)

Answer (score 1):

The [capitalization rules](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms229043.aspx) say:

> - Do capitalize both characters of two-character acronyms, except the first word of a camel-cased identifier.
>
>   A property named DBRate is an example of a short acronym (DB) used
>     as the first word of a Pascal-cased identifier. A parameter named
>     ioChannel is an example of a short acronym (IO) used as the first word
>     of a camel-cased identifier.
> - Do capitalize only the first character of acronyms with three or more characters, except the first word of a camel-cased identifier.
>
>   A class named XmlWriter is an example of a long acronym used as the
>     first word of a Pascal-cased identifier. A parameter named htmlReader
>     is an example of a long acronym used as the first word of a
>     camel-cased identifier.
> - Do not capitalize any of the characters of any acronyms, whatever their length, at the beginning of a camel-cased identifier.
>
>   A parameter named xmlStream is an example of a long acronym (xml)
>     used as the first word of a camel-cased identifier. A parameter named
>     dbServerName is an example of a short acronym (db) used as the first
>     word of a camel-cased identifier.

You violate these rules numerous times: `dataISO`, `TPDU`, `BITMAP`, `cboISOCommand`, `SendISO`, etc.

---

What is the point of this:

```
string dataLength = "019A";
string TPDU = "6001010000";
string MTI = "0100";
string BITMAP = "3020078020C00204";
string ProCode = "380000"; // 3
string Amount = "000000010000"; // 4
string STAN = "000031"; // 11
string POSEM = "051"; // 22
string PANSequence = "001"; // 23
string FunctionCode = "101"; // 24
string ConditionCode = "00"; // 25
string Track2 = "36484200000000009=15000000000000000000"; //35
string TerminalID = "00000000"; //41
string IdentificationCode = "000000000000000"; //42
string ReservedISO = "2725F2A02045882023C008407A0000000031010950500000080009A031407229C01009F0206000000000010";
ReservedISO +="9F03060000000000009F0902008C9F100706010A03A0A0029F1A0204589F1E0831313731313534399F26";
ReservedISO +="081344604C7E2C7B589F2701809F3303E0B0C89F34031E03009F3501229F360204379F3704746733F19F4";
ReservedISO +="104000000079F530152"; //55
string ReservedPrivate = "006000019"; //62

string total = dataLength + TPDU + MTI + BITMAP + ProCode + Amount + STAN + POSEM + PANSequence + FunctionCode + ConditionCode + Track2 + TerminalID + IdentificationCode + ReservedISO + ReservedPrivate;
```

- Are all of those string `const`? If so, why aren't they defined as such?
- The comments make no sense: `//55`, `//42`
- To me this feels like code that should be in a separate class, with the likes of `dataLength`, `TPDU` etc. being properties or `const`, and `total` being a get-only property with a more meaningful name.
- What is the point of `total`, considering you immediately assign its value to `dataISO`?
- They're currently all local variables, yet most of them are PascalCase when they should be camelCase.

---

Is `ControllerErrorArguments` a class you control? If so: why not have a version with the `String.Format()` functionality built-in?

---

Twice you do this cast: `(IPEndPoint)client.Client.RemoteEndPoint`. Do it once, store it in a variable, use that variable.

Comment: Noted thanks for answering. No the strings are not constant. I hardcoded all the data to be verified by the client-side. The comments //55 //42 represents the Data Field according to ISO8583. I just want wanted to know which data should be sent as hexadecimal and ASCII? @BCdotWEB